# In UML-Designer It's possible to add a class from another package to another package class diagram?

Tags: uml-designer

Using UML Designer, it's possible to add a class from another package to another package class diagram?

I have two packages: *pacakge1* and *package2*, in *package1* I have one class *MyClass*, I want to add this class *MyClass* to a diagram class into *package2*, it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already sovled the problem, since it's been long since asked.

You can click the green plus icon and get "Add existing elements" window, in which on can select elements to be placed in the diagram when you select "all elements".

[image]